# Passing definition of event handler as a lambda expression

Tags: c#, delegates, event-handling

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
        Watcher w = new Watcher();
        w.watch(@"someLocation", (() => { MoveFiles.Move() ; return 0; }));
}

public void watch(string pathName, Func< int> OnChanged)
{
            FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
            watcher.Path = pathName;
            watcher.Filter = "*.*";
            watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            Console.WriteLine("Press \'q\' to quit the sample.");
            while (Console.Read() != 'q') ;
}
```

I am trying to pass definition of `OnChanged` event as a lambda expression but I am getting

> Error: No Overload for Func matches the delegate "System.IO.FileSystemEventHandle"

I tried changing the delegate `Func<int>` to `Func<Object, FileSystemEventArgs, int>` but still get some error.

Please advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FileSystemEventHandler` delegate has exactly two parameters - sender `object` and `FileSystemEventArgs` argument. And it doesn't return any value. I.e. it's signature looks like:

```
public void FileSystemEventHandler(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
```

Lambda should match this signature - it should not return any values and it should accept two arguments as described above. You can use `FileSystemEventHandler` or `Action<object, FileSystemEventArgs>` delegate as method parameter:

```
public void watch(string pathName, FileSystemEventHandler OnChanged)
{
   // ...
   watcher.Created += OnChanged;
}
```

Passing lambda to this method:

```
w.watch(@"someLocation", (s,e) => MoveFiles.Move());
```

Note: there is no implicit conversion between `FileSystemEventHandler` and `Action<object, FileSystemEventArgs>` delegates. So if you'll use handler of `Action<object, FileSystemEventArgs>` type, then you should attach it this way:

```
watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
```

Comment: Please note that `new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged)` prevents it from being removed later, you need to use reflection to make it removable as the new delegate points to the delegate instead of the original object.

Answer (score 0):

`OnChanged` should have the signature

```
private static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{

}
```

Not `Func<int>`

You should pass an `Action<object, FileSystemEventArgs>` instead

See [its MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.changed(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2)

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Watcher w = new Watcher();
        w.watch(@"someLocation", (source, e) => { MoveFiles.Move(); });
    }


    public void watch(string pathName, FileSystemEventHandler OnChanged)
    {
        FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
        watcher.Path = pathName;
        watcher.Filter = "*.*";
        watcher.Created += OnChanged;
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        Console.WriteLine("Press \'q\' to quit the sample.");
        while (Console.Read() != 'q') ;
    }
```